# MATLAB: audioplayer()

Tags: matlab, audio

I am using the sound() function in MATLAB to generate a tone. The following function plays a tone for 4 seconds at 440Hz:

```
duration = 4
toneFreq = 440
samplesPerSecond = 44100; % the bit rate of the tone
y = sin(linspace(0, duration * toneFreq * 2 * pi, round(duration * samplesPerSecond))); % the equation of the sound wave
sound(y, samplesPerSecond); % play the sound wave at the specified bit rate
```

Occasionally (after using the function a few times), I get an error from MATLAB saying "can't register sound window". Having looked around the internet a bit, I notice this is a known bug in MATLAB (version R14 SP3) and so the general advice seems to be to use the ['audioplayer' function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/audioplayer.html) instead. So, I have updated my code to the following:

```
duration = 4
toneFreq = 440
samplesPerSecond = 44100; % the bit rate of the tone
y = sin(linspace(0, duration * toneFreq * 2 * pi, round(duration * samplesPerSecond))); % the equation of the sound wave
player = audioplayer(y, samplesPerSecond); % play the sound wave at the specified bit rate
play(player)
```

However, this does not produce a tone. Can anyone help in making this new code work?

Comment: Your new code is working for me. Since your old code was working for some time and them stopped, it's may be something related to Java or audio driver, I'm not sure. Have you tried to restart MATLAB or the computer?

Comment: The old code works, but occasionally it fails and produces the error message. I then have to restart MATLAB :(

Comment: I have found the root of the problem - my code is within a function of its own. Once the function ends, it stops the sound playing. Since the last action of my function is to play the tone, the sound is stopped before it really gets to start. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution - the problem seems to be that the audio playback stops when the function exits. So, I have had to change play() to playblocking(). This prevents control returning until the sound finishes. It's not the ideal solution however (it would be nice to pass control back to the parent function whilst the sound still plays), but for now it will do. If anyone can suggest a way to pass control back *and* play the whole sound, I would appreciate it. Here is the final code:

```
duration = 4
toneFreq = 440
samplesPerSecond = 44100; % the bit rate of the tone
y = sin(linspace(0, duration * toneFreq * 2 * pi, round(duration * samplesPerSecond))); % the equation of the sound wave
player = audioplayer(y, samplesPerSecond); % play the sound wave at the specified bit rate
playblocking(player)
```

Edit: A solution has also been found that allows play to continue after the function exits. See [MATLAB: Having audioplayer() continue to play after function ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706224/matlab-having-audioplayer-continue-to-play-after-function-ends).

Comment: I would recommend you to add to this answer that you have asked a new followup question, place the link and accept your answer.